# Embed ggplot2 Graph in Knitr Document: Unable to find function ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, knitr

I am working on a document and am using both `knitr` and `ggplot2`. I am new to `knitr` and TeX itself and therefore not overly familiar with all that I am doing.

When I open RStudio to do the work, I first run the following two commands:

```
require("knitr")
require("ggplot2")
```

I then click on the Compile PDF. I have the following code that throws an error:

```
<<histogram, echo=FALSE, fig.align='center'>>=
summary(los$hosp_svc)
summary(los$Pt_Age)

binsize = diff(range(los$Pt_Age)/30)
ggplot(los, aes(x = Pt_Age)) + 
  geom_histogram(binwidth = binsize, fill = "red", 
                 alpha = 0.315, colour = 'black') +
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank()) +
  xlab("Patient Age in Years") +
  ylab("Frequency/Count") +
  ggtitle("Histogram of Patient Age")
@
```

The error that I am getting is that the ggplot function could not be found, which is odd because if I just run the above code in the console the graph produces just find, so I know the package is loaded and available for use.

Any thoughts?

Thank you,

Comment: Try putting `library(ggplot2)` into your script (the .Rnw file).

Comment: Worked like a charm, please put that as the solution and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When working with .Rnw files (or .Rmd files), be sure to include any `library` calls in your script (see below).  When you press the "Compile PDF" button, the R code in your script is submitted to a new instance of R to prevent anything in your current environment from mucking up the results.  This might seem a little strange, but is good for reproducibility.  So objects that aren't created explicitly via your script and packages that aren't called explicitly in your script will be forgotten as soon as you hit "Compile PDF"

```
<<histogram, echo=FALSE, fig.align='center'>>= 
library(ggplot2)
summary(los$hosp_svc) 
summary(los$Pt_Age)

binsize = diff(range(los$Pt_Age)/30) 
ggplot(los, aes(x = Pt_Age)) + 
  geom_histogram(binwidth = binsize, 
                 fill = "red", 
                 alpha = 0.315, 
                 colour = 'black') + 
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), 
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank()) + 
  xlab("Patient Age in Years") + 
  ylab("Frequency/Count") + 
  ggtitle("Histogram of Patient Age") 
@
```

Comment: Nice answer.  For later readers, you might note that it is only necessary to load a package once in the .Rnw or .Rmd file even if multiple chunks rely on the package.

Comment: @lawyeR I have loaded ggplot2 `library(ggplot2)` in my first chunk but while plotting in different chunk I get error `could not find function "ggplot"`. Plotting works fine while executing the chunk but while knitting I get this error message.Any reason why it is not picking the library?

Comment: Are you in a project (RStudio)?   Does the first chunk have ", cache = FALSE" as an argument?  And, does the same error occur if you put ggplot2::ggplot(... in the chunk where you first call it?